# is this code properly secured

Tags: security

The input will be an address. This is what I gather from looking at the Codex. See here: [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

```
$wpdb->insert($address_table, array('address' => $address),array('%s'));
```

Comment: Where does `$address_table` come from?

Comment: @chrisguitarguy : See the user's [other question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/125780/21376).

Comment: `$address_table = $wpdb->prefix . "address_table";` Mainly, I was enquiring about the way I am using %s.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this seems to be appropriate use of `insert()` method, which does call `prepare()` method on data internally. Note that `%s` is considered to be default for it and can simply be omitted, if no other data and formats are involved.